# jQuery - using .append() in combination with .fadeIn()

Tags: jquery

I am using to jQuery to dynamically add a form input to an ordered list using append(), which works great:

```
$newItem = $('input[type=text]').val();

$("#toDoList").append('<li class="listItem">' + $newItem + '<div class="delete">X</div></li>');
```

The new list item appears without problems.

However, I would like to use a fadeIn() effect for new items that are added, which I don't get working.

I tried the following without success:

```
$("#toDoList").append('<li class="listItem">' + $newItem + '<div class="delete">X</div></li>').fadeIn('slow');
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Can you put together a JSFiddle with some HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you first need to hide the element, as it's already visible when appended so `fadeIn` appears to do nothing. Try this:

```js
var $newItem = 'Foo';
$('<li class="listItem">' + $newItem + '<div class="delete">X</div></li>')
    .hide()
    .appendTo('#toDoList')
    .fadeIn('slow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="toDoList"></ul>
```

Comment: Ya beat me to it... I was in the middle of creating a fiddle, so I just dropped your stuff in instead-- here it is for sng's [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdLmd46x/)

Answer (score 0):

`fadeIn` is not working because when the new content is appended, it is automatically displayed normally. If you set the style of the appended attribute to `display: none` either inline as in my example or in CSS, and then call `fadeIn` it will work. See snippet below:

```js
var newItem = $('input[type=text]').val();

$("#toDoList").append('<li style="display: none;" class="listItem">' + newItem + '<div class="delete">X</div></li>');
$("li").fadeIn("slow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test">
<ul id="toDoList">
</ul>
```